# How do I fetch image name from static resource by referencing a local json file?

Tags: javascript, react-native, require

> user.json

```
[
    {
    'studentId': '17sta001',
    'fullName': 'Nuzmus Sayeed Nabil',
    'bloodGroup': 'a+',
    'district': 'Kustia',
    'photoUrl': 'pic1.jpg'
},
{
    'studentId': '17sta002',
    'fullName': 'Asif Ahmead',
    'photoUrl': 'pic1.jpg',
},
{
    'studentId': '17sta003',
    'fullName': 'Mr. A',
    'photoUrl': 'pic2.jpg'
},
{
    'studentId': '17sta004',
    'fullName': 'Mr. B',
    'photoUrl': 'pic3.jpg'
},
{
    'studentId': '17sta004',
    'fullName': 'Mr. C',
    'photoUrl': 'pic4.jpg'
},
{
    'studentId': '17sta004',
    'fullName': 'Mr. D',
    'photoUrl': 'pic5.jpg'
},
{
    'studentId': '17sta004',
    'fullName': 'Mr. E',
    'photoUrl': 'pic6.jpg'
},
{
    'studentId': '17sta004',
    'fullName': 'Mr. F',
    'photoUrl': 'pic7.jpg'
}
]

App.js
  renderUser() {
return Data.map((user) => {
  return (
    <View key={Date.now()}>
      <Text>{user.studentId}</Text>
      <Text>{user.fullName}</Text>
      <Image style={{ width: '100%', height: 200 }} source={} />
    </View>
  )
})
  }
```

> Now how can I get loaded photoUrl inside source={/* here */}
>
> I have image in my directory ./src/images/pic1.jpg
>
> require('./src/images/' + user.photoUrl) doesn't work

**Please help me, how can I solve it. I try lot of ways but every time I failed failed**
Is it possible to use require() with some tips or critical cases. I have spent a lot of time to solve this. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is a premise that all files are in the same path.

```js
<Image style={{ width: '100%', height: 200 }} source={require('./src/images/'+ user.photoUrl +'')} />
```

Comment: It's through an error, although all the image file in the same path (src/images/). It says that invalid call at line no 16!  What can I do regarding that? Please help

Comment: what is line 16?

Comment: `<Image style={{ width: '100%', height: 200 }} source={require('./src/images/'+ user.photoUrl +'')} />`

Comment: @Md.A.Barik What kind of error are you saying? Is it a syntax error?

Comment: I got the solution. But your solution will not work anymore